# iOS Storyboard - TableView Embedded in Container with Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have a tableview that is embedded in a container, its using prototype cells so in theory I don't know how many cells there may be (realistically 1 - 3). At the minute, I end up with a bunch of empty rows underneath the table cell that is populated. Changing the height of the container can sort of 'hide' these but it isn't the solution.

How can I get the containers height to change depending on the number of items in the embedded tableview? Or alternatively if anyone knows if there is some magic "don't add any empty rows if there are only 1 or 2 items in my table view" setting?

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: apologies, edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the frame of the Container with the embedded TableView based on the contentSize of the TableView. Note: depending on how you setup the TableView data sourse, the contentSize property of the TableView might not be set in viewWillAppear. Instead, you will have to use the viewDidAppear method of the ViewController that has all of your Container views. Also, you might need to call reloadData on your TableView after you set the frame of the Contatiner view.

Comment: how do i set the frame of the container? CTRL + drag?

Comment: This is something you will have to do in code. You should have a UIViewController subclass corresponding to the view that holds all of your Containers. From your UIViewController subclass, you will have an IBOutlet to the Container view you want to resize. In either the viewWillAppear viewDidAppear methods you will set the Container.frame property to the content size of your TableView.

Comment: how do i get the height of the tableview from the parent viewController?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `-prepareForSegue:` method to make your parent view controller a delegate of the table view controller. When cells are added/removed from the table view, it can call a method on the parent view controller and pass the info; the parent view controller can then change the size of the container based on that information.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html